# How to count lines backwards from log in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to count the amount of pallets on a location where you can't see on the location how many pallets there are. The only way to find out is to assume that you can count backwards from the log where it's logged what pallets have been moved to that location.

**Location quantity**

```
LOCATION    QUANTITY
Loc_1       20
```

**Log**

```
MOVED_TO_LOCATION    QUANTITY         PALLET_NUMBER
Loc_1                5                13                
Loc_1                5                12
Loc_1                5                11
Loc_1                5                10 <--  Count the lines from here and up (count = 4).
Loc_1                5                9
...
```

What I tried so far was some **CROSS APPLY** where I joined the location to the log and counted the results. Which returned 13 (instead of 4) because it didn't count away the ones that were already gone. So how would I count backwards and only gets the first 4 rows?

```
-- Query returns 13 rows.
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT PALL_NUM
FROM LOG 
WHERE MOVED_TO_LOCATION = LOCATION
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) LOG
```

I assume you could somehow incrementally count up the amount in the log from latest to earliest timestamp until the quantity is more or equal in the log to the current quantity on the location. But I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

**Pseudocode**

```
Quantity on location = 20

Row 1 in log: 5. 
    20 - 5 = 15 remaining. 

Row 2 in log: 5. 
    15 - 5 = 10 remaining.

Row 3 in log: 5. 
    10 - 5 = 5 remaining.

Row 4 in log: 5. 
    5 - 5 = 0 remaining. 

Then stop and return the rows.
```

---

### Edit 1: Expected results and what I have

**Location quantity**

```
LOCATION    QUANTITY
Loc_1       20
Loc_2       10


SELECT BS.LOCATION, TL.PALL_NUM, BS.QUANTITY
FROM BATCH_STOCK BS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANS_LOG TL 
    ON TL.ITEM_NUM = BS.ITEM_NUM AND LOC_TO = BS.LOCATION
ORDER BY BS.LOCATION
```

**Result**

```
LOCATION          PALL_NUM          QUANTITY
Loc_2             16                5
Loc_2             15                5
Loc_2             14                5
Loc_1             13                5
Loc_1             12                5
Loc_1             11                5
Loc_1             10                5
...               ...
Loc_1             1                 5
```

This is just an extended version from the first question. But shows the output I would get if I didn't count backwards in the log. So for example Loc_2 would only have 2 pallets with quantity still on them but return 3 pallets because 3 pallets have been moved to that location. And Loc_1 would return 13 pallets but the first 9 have already been "picked" so they aren't there anymore.

**Expected result**

```
LOCATION          PALL_NUM
Loc_2             16
Loc_2             15
Loc_1             13
Loc_1             12
Loc_1             11
Loc_1             10
```

---

### Edit 2: Table structure

**BATCH_STOCK**

```
LOCATION = PK NVARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
QTY = NUMERIC (9,2) NOT NULL
```

**TRANS_LOG**

```
PALL_NUM = BIGINT NOT NULL
LOC_TO = NVARCHAR(16) NULL
QTY = NUMERIC(9,2) NULL
```

Comment: Can you please show us your expected output? You want `Pall_Num` or just count (which is 4 in this case)

Comment: My expected put would be PALL_NUM: 13, 12, 11, 10 in this case for location LOC_1. Then for example PALL_NUM: 16, 15 for LOC_2 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a running total? This will return you the 4 rows:

```
select * from (
  select *, 
    sum(QUANTITY) over (order by PALLET_NUMBER desc) as Quant
  from yourtable
) X where Quant <= 20
```

That only works with full pallets, if you need to include rows for partial quantities, this should work then:

```
select * from (
  select *, isnull(lag(Quant) over (order by PALLET_NUMBER desc),0) as NextQuant
  from (
    select *, 
      sum(QUANTITY) over (order by PALLET_NUMBER desc) as Quant
    from yourtable
  ) X 
) Y where NextQuant < 15
```

**Update**, added examples with the new tables included in the question

```
select * from (
  select *, 
    sum(QUANTITY) over (partition by LOCATION order by PALL_NUM desc) as Quant
  from #TRANS_LOG
) X join #BATCH_STOCK S on S.QUANTITY >= X.Quant and S.LOCATION = X.LOCATION


select * from (
  select *, isnull(lag(Quant) over (partition by LOCATION order by PALL_NUM desc),0) as NextQuant
  from (
    select *, 
      sum(QUANTITY) over (partition by LOCATION order by PALL_NUM desc) as Quant
    from #TRANS_LOG
  ) X 
) Y join #BATCH_STOCK S on S.QUANTITY > Y.NextQuant and S.LOCATION = Y.LOCATION
```

Results:

```
    LOCATION    PALL_NUM    QUANTITY    Quant   LOCATION    QUANTITY
1   Loc_1       13          5           5       Loc_1       20
2   Loc_1       12          5           10      Loc_1       20
3   Loc_1       11          5           15      Loc_1       20
4   Loc_1       10          5           20      Loc_1       20
5   Loc_2       16          5           5       Loc_2       10
6   Loc_2       15          5           10      Loc_2       10

    LOCATION    PALL_NUM    QUANTITY    Quant   NextQuant   LOCATION    QUANTITY
1   Loc_1       13          5           5       0           Loc_1       20
2   Loc_1       12          5           10      5           Loc_1       20
3   Loc_1       11          5           15      10          Loc_1       20
4   Loc_1       10          5           20      15          Loc_1       20
5   Loc_2       16          5           5       0           Loc_2       10
6   Loc_2       15          5           10      5           Loc_2       10
```

[Example](http://rextester.com/ZYH26613) that I made

Comment: This somewhat works for single specific locations but it falls apart when I try to use in in a more general sense (with multiple different locations) in a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: If there's more locations, just add `partition by location` into the sum / lag

Comment: The problem is that it picks 4 different pallets on 3 different locations. Where the final result should be around 60 different pallets on 50 different locations. I've edited the question to clarify the question if that maybe helps.

Comment: At least in my test both of those work just fine. I'll add the examples

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well for me, the results look similar to what I want. I'll just need to double check it and be back in a few days to accept the answer if it indeed was correct.

Comment: This is incredibly close... but when I change Quantity on the location to 21 instead of 20 it should pick up the next pallet number too. Since there is 1 quantity left of that pallet.

Edit: Actually only the first select had this problem. I'll try to apply the second one!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Here is what i have tried so far.  I have used recursive CTE to achieve the expected output.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE #tLocationQty
(
  Location VARCHAR(10),
  Quantity int
)

INSERT INTO #tLocationQty  VALUES('Loc_1',20)   
INSERT INTO #tLocationQty  VALUES('Loc_2',10)
```

Second table schema

```
CREATE TABLE #tLog 
(
  MoveToLocation VARCHAR(10),
  Quantity int,
  PALL_NUM int
)

INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_1',5, 13)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_1',5, 12)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_1',5, 11)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_1',5, 10)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_1',5, 9)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_2',5, 16)   
INSERT INTO #tLog  VALUES('Loc_2',5, 15)
```

and below is the query.

**Note:** - I have not use `order by` clause. You have to use it as per your requirement.

**Query**

```
;WITH myCTE
AS 
(
    SELECT Location, Quantity AS Qty FROM #tLocationQty

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MoveToLocation, (Qty - t.Quantity) AS Qty FROM #tLog t
    INNER JOIN myCTE
    ON myCTE.Location = t.MoveToLocation
    WHERE myCTE.Qty > 0
),
DistLocation
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM myCTE WHERE qty > 0 
),
RowCnt
AS
(
    SELECT Location, COUNT(DISTINCT Qty) AS Cnt FROM myCTE WHERE qty > 0 
    GROUP BY Location
)
--SELECT * FROM RowCnt
SELECT * FROM DistLocation
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT top 1 Cnt FROM RowCnt r WHERE r.location = location) 
    PALL_NUM 
    FROM #tLog t
    WHERE t.MoveToLocation = location 
) c
```

**Output**

```
Location    PALL_NUM
Loc_1       13
Loc_1       12
Loc_1       11
Loc_1       10
Loc_2       15
Loc_2       16
```

Comment: After trying to apply this I got the following error. Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Location" of recursive query "myCTE".

Comment: @Danieboy: Its perfectly running fine in my sql server instance. I have used SQL Server 2014. Please check it once again. Let me create SQL Fiddle for you.

Comment: Well I can run your code with your tables. But when I try to apply it to my own tables I get the error.

Comment: @Danieboy: Please post your table structure in your question. So that i can help you properly.

Comment: I've added the table structure to the question now.

Comment: @Danieboy: In `BATCH_STOCK` table location column is - NVARCHAR(13) and in `TRANS_LOG` table column LOC_TO is NVARCHAR(16). This is the reason you get that error.

Comment: Yeah I kind of realized it as I typed it... Maybe I'll have to try and change it. Can maybe try to cast it to the same type to see if the solution holds up and gives me the result that I want.

Comment: I'm gonna need to come back to this after the weekend sadly. Thanks a lot for the help!